# NSDate from 12 hour time

Tags: nsdate, nsdateformatter

I am trying to create an NSDate object from 2 NSStrings.

One of the NSStrings is of the form ==> mm/dd/yyyy (g.date in the following sample)

The other is of the form ==> hh:mm am/pm (g.time in the following sample)

The following code:

```
for(Game *g in _games) {
    NSDateFormatter *format = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [format setDateFormat:@"dd'/'MM'/'yyyy HH':'mm"];
    NSString *dateString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", g.date, g.time];
    dateString = [dateString substringToIndex:[dateString length]-3];
    NSDate *date = [format dateFromString:dateString];
    NSLog(@"%@ ==> %@", dateString, date);
}
```

produces inaccurate and unpredictable output like this :

```
2012-04-30 19:39:06.923 MLP[27866:fb03] 05/03/2012 8:30 ==> 2012-03-05 13:30:00 +0000
2012-04-30 19:39:06.923 MLP[27866:fb03] 05/03/2012 8:45 ==> 2012-03-05 13:45:00 +0000
2012-04-30 19:39:06.924 MLP[27866:fb03] 03/29/2012 9:30 ==> (null)
2012-04-30 19:39:06.924 MLP[27866:fb03] 03/29/2012 8:15 ==> (null)
2012-04-30 19:39:06.925 MLP[27866:fb03] 03/01/2012 9:15 ==> 2012-01-03 14:15:00 +0000
2012-04-30 19:39:06.925 MLP[27866:fb03] 05/03/2012 9:00 ==> 2012-03-05 14:00:00 +0000
2012-04-30 19:39:06.926 MLP[27866:fb03] 03/29/2012 9:00 ==> (null)
2012-04-30 19:39:06.926 MLP[27866:fb03] 05/03/2012 9:15 ==> 2012-03-05 14:15:00 +0000
```

I am cutting off the AM/PM part of the time string because I cannot find out how to indicate it's presence in the NSDateFormatter syntax. How can I do this?

Help appreciated,

Pachun

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out for anyone who may run into this in the future. This is what fixed it:

```
// Sort by date
- (NSComparisonResult)compare:(Game *)g {

    // Parse date's strings to an NSDate
    NSDateFormatter *format = [NSDateFormatter new];
    [format setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy hh:mma"];

    NSString *otherDateString;
    NSString *myDateString;

    if([g.time length]==7)
        otherDateString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ 0%@", g.date, g.time];
    else otherDateString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", g.date, g.time];
    if([_time length]==7)
        otherDateString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ 0%@", _date, _time];
    else otherDateString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", _date, _time];

    NSDate *otherDate = [format dateFromString:otherDateString];
    NSDate *myDate = [format dateFromString:myDateString];

    return [myDate compare:otherDate];
}
```